# How to find Information gain in text classification?

Tags: text, classification

I am working on text classification using Decision Tree which uses information gain as the main value for categorisation of text document. I have extracted few features by TF*IDF value. But I not able to figure out how exactly information gain should be calculated? There are some articles suggesting about this but none of them are very clear how to apply it to Text files.

Comment: if you find my answer helpful you can upvote and select my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use **weka** for calculating **information gain** . in weka `InfoGainAttributeEval.java`
class will calculate IG for the word with respect to document.[check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063206/information-gain-calculation-for-a-text-file) this may help you.

Comment: @Subodh Mankar if any problem ask me